# Get the value of certain column in datagridview before and after changes

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i have a problem where i can't solve it by myself. And before i start, it is important to let you guys know that

**This problem i wrote from the beginning to the end, i want to make you guys understand properly what my problem is, for those who are lazy to read this, please forgive me, i am not attach any code in here, only just logic**

Probably people in this forum could help me. But, i already got a solution to my problem (but only the logic, i can't prove it by code and don't know where to start)

**Well, here is my case:**

`I got a Quantity column in DataGridView, and i got a feature where user could edit the Quantity column in DataGridView and automatically updating the Quantity value in the Database.`

**For Example (still at the case):**

`I have 1000 on Quantity in the Database, and i enter the value of 50 in the Quantity column in system and after that i add to the DataGridView by clicking a "OK" button, once clicked, the Quantity in the Database should update it Quantity become 950, from 1000. Because i use a formula` **valueOfQuantityInDatabase - valueOfQuantityInSystem**, `it update properly and successful`

**Here is my problem goes:**

`Let's say i got a DataGridView with Quantity column and the value of it is 50` **(This make a Quantity value in Database become 950)** `and let's say customer want to add his Quantity from 50 to 150, so i change the value of Quantity in DataGridView to 150 from 50, and when i click "OK" button, the Database should update based on the formula` **valueOfQuantityInDatabase - valueOfQuantityInSystem**, `and the Quantity in Database should have 850 in Quantity value` **(Because 1000 - 150)**, `but it is not as i expected, the Quantity value in database is 800` **(Because first time i add is 50, so the Quantity in database is 950, next i add another 150 and the Quantity in database is 800)**, `so it is like first entered value + second entered value.`

**Here is what i want:**

`Whenever user edit the Quantity in DataGridView, it should goes to this formula` **valueOfQuantityInDatabase - valueOfQuantityInSystem** ------ **(So, whenever user change the Quantity value in DataGridView, let's say it change to 150 from 50, the Quantity in Database should recognized it and minus with current value of Quantity in DataGridView (150), not the older one (50)**

**Here is my solution that i came with:**

1. **Get the first value of Quantity in Database before it was changed (1000)**
2. **Get how many value of Quantity that has been added from user by formula** `Quantity in DataGridView after changes - Quantity in DataGridView before changes` **and plus it with the formula** `Quantity in DataGridView after changes - Quantity in DataGridView before changes`

But i don't know how to get the solution 1 nor 2. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much! Your answer i appreciate so much!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to change the design, change the way you update the Quantity in the database. I dont know what is the data source of your gridview. If its a list of items, whenever user update the quantity in the grid dont update the change to the database, rather just update the data source, may be value in the list of order items. Quantity should only be updated when user is done with the order and click Save button.

In this approach you dont have to maintain any previous quantity of the added product, User can update the quantity any number of time, You dont have to keep track of it, it will make your code complex. when user clicks save just get the current quantity in the grid and just update the database.

Comment: yeah, i already could get the current quantity in the grid, but my problem is that i want to update the database based on number of Quantity in the database before any changes has been made. And, what do you mean by change? change only the logic or change entire design of datagridview?

Comment: Now how do you update the quantity in the database ? Everytime user changes the quantity in the grid you update the quantity in the database as well ?

Comment: Yeah, when user adding data to the datagridview, it update the quantity in the database and add entire data to the table and display it as datagridview. When user editing data in the datagridview also (when changes has been made), the quantity in the database will be updated.

Comment: that approach is not recommended. thats complex. Bind a list of items to the grid and add a save button and update the changes to the database only when users click the save button, whenever user changes the value in the gridview update the list that has been set as a data source of the grid. so everytime when user update some value on the grid you will update the list not the database. and when users saves the changes go and update the database base don the values in the list. this would be the best approach

Comment: and sir, how do i bind a list of items to the grid? Whereas item will be added to the grid once user filled up all of the textboxes.

Comment: First create a class with properties each of these properties will represent each column in the grid. assume you have created class Order, Datasource of your grid will be List<Order>. each Order object in the list will represent each row of the grid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38231/discussion-between-accessdenied-and-kaoru)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous techniques to capture any change in any cells in DataGridView (DGV). One way is to exploit the two events of DGV:

1. CellBeginEdit
2. CellEndEdit

Here is the trick...

you can declare two private fields (let, _oldValue & _newValue) in the class where you are using DGV to calculate the values. Then subscription of the 2 events can be as follows:

```
private void dataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    _oldValue = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
}


private void dataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    _newValue = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

    if (_newValue != _oldValue)
    {
        // YOUR LOGIC SHOULD START FROM HERE
    }
}
```

Now I am focusing on your problem...

If you want to achieve your solution 1, then you may put your logic in the above location to save the database value of the cell for the very first time it changes.

Though solution 2 is not clear enough to me, you may just do the following in the above location:

- Save the database value
- deduct the _newValue from database value
- Store it back to the database

But invoking database every time the cell changes may be very time-consuming. So you should look for any speedy solution.